# How to create a gRPC ContextPropagationToken

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I'm creating an in memory gRPC channel for use in testing. (This is in C#). This involves implementing a call invoker, that in turn involves implementing a server call context. One of the methods you need to implement has the following signature

```cs
protected abstract ContextPropagationToken CreatePropagationTokenCore(ContextPropagationOptions options);
```

Unfortunately, I can't see any way to create such a token. It turns out for my current purposes this isn't needed, but is there a way short of reflection to create or get such an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps set context, [here's the implementation in asp.net core's version](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/afd37e4d0a3d61d581d265b0754408ea3799ab1d/src/Grpc.AspNetCore.Server/Internal/HttpContextServerCallContext.cs#L322-L327) - so: I wouldn't get too excited.

```cs
protected override ContextPropagationToken CreatePropagationTokenCore(ContextPropagationOptions options)
{
    // TODO(JunTaoLuo, JamesNK): Currently blocked on ContextPropagationToken implementation in Grpc.Core.Api
    // https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/40
    throw new NotImplementedException("CreatePropagationToken will be implemented in a future version.");
}
```

You weren't imagining it.